Tracking File Arrivals in Nested Folders Using Databricks File Arrival Trigger
I'm currently exploring a file arrival trigger with Databricks, but my data is organized into nested folders representing various sources. For instance:
source1
|-- file1
|-- file.csv
|-- file2
|-- file.csv
My goal is to determine the specific location within the nested folder structure where a file, such as file.csv, has arrived, along with capturing the file name. This allows me to streamline my workflow by utilizing a single job for multiple files.
Could someone provide guidance on how to achieve this effectively within Databricks?
Thank you!
I am able to access for single file at a time, I want to trace multiple subfolders and need to know in which folder file has arrived with its file name.

Add more details of your approach and error details you are facing.

You can use file arrival trigger itself to get the notifications when new files arrive under parent folder.

A file arrival trigger can be configured to monitor the root of a Unity Catalog external location or volume, or a subpath of an external location or volume. For example, for the Unity Catalog root volume /Volumes/mycatalog/myschema/myvolume/, the following are valid paths for a file arrival trigger:

/Volumes/mycatalog/myschema/myvolume/  
/Volumes/mycatalog/myschema/myvolume/mydirectory/  

This would help in triggering the notifications whenever any file in the parent folder arrives.
In order to track the file path, you can add _metadata column in the dataframe while reading the file.
For more details, check the documentation
